# Install CentOS 7 Desktop in Windows using Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm a beginner in docker.

I need to install docker in my  local windows PC ( Desktop, 64 bit , windows 10, 4GB RAM)

In that i need to install CentOS 7 ( with desktop access)

In that CentOS 7 container i need to install google-chrome and firefox Software in that desktop.

Answer (score 6):

2017: You can use [ConSol/docker-headless-vnc-container](https://github.com/ConSol/docker-headless-vnc-container)
(2022: no longer maintained, though)

> The repository contains a collection of Docker images with headless VNC environments.
>
> Each Docker image is installed with the following components:
>
> - Desktop environment Xfce4 or IceWM
> - VNC-Server (default VNC port 5901)
> - noVNC
> - HTML5 VNC client (default http port 6901)
> - Browsers:
>
>   - Mozilla Firefox
>   - Chromium

To use those containers, browse to https://github.com/ConSol/docker-headless-vnc-container/blob/master.
Or use a [VNCViewer](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/windows/).

You will have access to the CentOS environment, running Chrome or Firefox:

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConSol/docker-headless-vnc-container/master/.pics/vnc_container_view.png]

Comment: This is not being maintained anymore, according to the note provided in the shared link.

Comment: @GürayHatipoğlu Thank You for the feedback. I have edited the answer to make the "archive" status clear. Did you find (in 2022) an alternative project which would provide the same service?

Comment: thank you for rapid consideration, first. 
I found a few ways but they were not fully functional, I will provide it here when I do find a one.

Comment: @GürayHatipoğlu OK, that will be much appreciated.